# Resize all images on a joomla mobile page

Tags: javascript, resize, image, getelementsbytagname

I am trying to make all images width 50% if mobile.
To check if now is mobile is not problem.

I tried:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('img').style.width="50%";
```

it's not working. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByTagName('img')
```

will return a NodeList, not an individual element.

To make your code work, you will need to first assign that NodeList to a variable, then loop through and apply your change to each individually:

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

for(var i = 0, l = imgs.length; i < l; ++i){
  imgs[i].style.width = '50%';
}
```